# What is a good practice for save value in database int or char?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I know its a silly question but I want to know what is a good practice when I save a int value in database instead of char.

When I want to save weeks in database.

I think if we save a char value in database its more descriptive.
So tell me which one is good and why?
There is any performance issues or not?

Comment: You save string data as character strings.  You save numeric data as numbers -- and, if the data is an integer, then you save it as an integer.  This is neither difficult nor counter-intuitive.

Comment: This article does a great explaining the problems with using the wrong datatypes. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: Both answers you currently have are great. Personally, I can't decide which is better, that's why I've upvoted both. The only thing that they are missing is the link provided in Sean Lange's comment. Aaron Bertrand's Bad habbits series is a must read for everyone working with databases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char` does not make it more descriptive. If you are going to use that value for anything in the database it will have to be converted to a number anyhow.

If the max value is going to be 52/53 (depending on week/isoweek) then use `tinyint`. Otherwise use some other [**`integer`** data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx).

Another potential issue is sorting. If you are going to sort on week, are you going to store leading zeros so they sort in order just to use a `char` data type, or leave it sorting as `1, 11, 12..`?

Comment: voted this for the very important hint about *sorting*!

Answer (score 3):

This sentence ist the problem:

> I think if we save a char value in database its more descriptive

The values in a database **should not be designed to be descriptive**.

One should **always store values in the appropriate data types!**

Just imagine you have the need to calculate a difference. You would have to split/parse the string, cast it to a numeric type, do the computation and re-format the output.

**Descriptive** is a word you should only use in connection with presentation layer, reporting and frontend.